# Azure Arm template copy function for VM and Datadisks

Tags: azure, azure-rm-template

I am using copy to create multiple VM's and want to have multiple datadisks for each vm.
I know i can do it this way:

```
              {
              "name": "[concat('dataDisk-',parameters('vm-name'),'-0',copyIndex(1))]",
              "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('dataDisksize')]",
              "lun": 0,
              "createOption": "Empty"
              },
              {
              "name": "[concat('dataDisk1-',parameters('vm-name'),'-0',copyIndex(1))]",
              "diskSizeGB": "[parameters('dataDisksize')]",
              "lun": 1,
              "createOption": "Empty"
              }
```

Now I have to create 20 disks with the same name and this doesn't seem to be good workaround. Getting issue with disk name while using copy. For my case i can use the same disksize for all 20 disks

Answer (score 1):

You can use the copy element to repeat properties:

```
"copy": [
            {
              "name": "dataDisks",
              "count": "[parameters('numberOfDataDisks')]",
              "input": {
                "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
                "createOption": "Empty",
                "diskSizeGB": 1023
              }
            }
          ]
```

More information here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/copy-properties

Comment: Thanks !  Problem is with the naming convention of the Disk. It throws an error when second vm is getting depoyed. I am using copy loop for vms also

Comment: You could concatenate in the "name" parameter a combination of string like `dataDisk` and the index of the copy iteration `[copyIndex('dataDisks')]` using the concat function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/template-functions-array#concat

Comment: This way names won't be repeated.

Answer (score 0):

> Now I have to create 20 disks with the same name and this doesn't seem
> to be good workaround. Getting issue with disk name while using copy.

Creating multiple disks using same name is impossible. you need `concat` either `copyindex` values to disk name or the `VMnames` to the Names of the disk..

In our template we have used the `copy function` block in the below manner to deploy multiple disks for a single virtual Machine & we have tested this in our local environment which is working fine.

**Here is the ARM template that we have created :**

```html
{
  "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
       "dataDiskCount": {
      "type": "int","minvalue" : 1,"maxValue" :20,"defaultValue" : 4,
      "metadata": {
        "description": "number of data disks."
      }
    }
  },
  "variables": {}
  "resources": [
    {
       "copy": [
            {
              "name": "dataDisks",
              "count": "[parameters('dataDiskCount')]",
              "input": {
                "diskSizeGB": "20",
                "lun": "[copyIndex('dataDisks')]",
                "createOption": "Empty",
                "name":"[concat('disk',copyIndex('dataDisks'),'dk')]"
              }
            }
    },
    "outputs": {}
}
```

**Here is the sample output screen shot for reference:**

[image]

Comment: thanks venkat! what i meant was naming convention. In the above template you arent using vm copy loop. If you use vm copy and when vm 2 tries to deploy it will throw an error for datadisk name(its already been assigned to vm 1). I dont want to randomly generate disk name